# print (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).date() returning NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using

```
print (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).date()
```

in Python 3.6.4 which is returning below error.

The same command is working is python 2.

```
>>> print (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).date()
2020-11-06 16:24:24.728051
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: did you try removing date i Idont think you need it at the end or what is you really trying to do? oh and import datetime

Comment: first  ``` import datetime```   ```print (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=7))``` if you want to use your own code

Comment: You are calling `.date()` on the result of `print()` - which is None (note that the date was successfully printed, before the error).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta    
d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
```